# Do there exist functions satisfying this property?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers

Do there exist functions $f_n : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ such that:

- $f_n(\zeta_n^k z) = \zeta_n^k f_n(z)$
- $f_n(z_1 + z_2) = f_n(z_1) + f_n(z_2)$
- $f_n(\mathbb{Q}) = 0$

where $\zeta_n$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity and for all $k \in \{0,...,n-1\}$?

For example: for $n=2$, $f_2(z) = \mathrm{Im}(z)$ satisfies this.

Comment: I'm guessing you want $f_n$ to not be identically zero?

Comment: if you drop the third requirement then any linear transformation would work; i.e for any $a\in\Bbb{C}$, let $ f_a(z):= az$.

Comment: If $\zeta_n$ is just an arbitrary root of unity, then one can take $\zeta_ n = 1$, so the first condition doesn't say anything.

Comment: For general $n$, $\zeta_n$ I would guess there are no *explicit* examples; they would involve finding a basis for $\Bbb C$ as a vector space over the field $\Bbb Q(\zeta_n)$.

Comment: @AlejandroEpelde Thank you for the edits, and that makes sense, I'll give it some thought.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks, I removed the line saying the third requirement might be dropped.

Comment: @cos_dm_math21 I intended to say that any $n$th root of unity can be pulled out of $f_n$, not a fixed one. I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: It is immediate that any locally bounded at some point such function is constant on the parallel lines defined by the roots of unity, so in particular if there are two such not parallel ($n \ge 3$) it must be zero everywhere, while for $n=2$ we get real multiples of the imaginary part) otherwise one can use a basis of the complex numbers over the corresponding field (rationals plus roots) that contains $1$ and send each element arbitrarily except $1$ which gets sent to zero, extending uniquely by linearity

Comment: @Conrad Can you explain why such a function that is locally bounded must be constant on these parallel lines? If you can post this as an answer I will accept. Also, is there a standard construction for such a basis of the complex numbers over cyclotomic fields?

Comment: It might be useful to consider $F_n=f_n^n$, so that $F_n(\zeta_n^k z)=\zeta_n^{kn}F_n(z)=F_n(z)$

Comment: Any additive function that is locally bounded at a point  (bounded in a small neighborhood) is locally bounded at any point so in particular at zero; but then on a small annulus there $|f| \le m$ hence $|f(z)/z| \le M$ there; now $f(rz)=rf(z)$ for rational $r$ so $f(z)/z$ is unchanged when $z\to rz$, implies that $|f(w)| \le M|w|$ for all small enough $w$  as they are rational multiples of some $z$ in the annulus above; hence $f$ continuous at zero, hence everywhere by additivity; but now $f$ is periodic with dense periods on any line as above, hence is constant there